# QEMU fail on riscv compressed ISA

Tags: compression, qemu

QEMU thinks that page crossing 4B instruction is 2B (compressed).

Has anyone encountered this issue ?  Is there a fix ?

Answer (score 0):

If you think you have found a bug in QEMU's riscv emulation, the best thing to do is first to check whether it is present in the most recent version of QEMU, and if it is still unfixed, to report it, either in the upstream bug tracker at https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu or by emailing the qemu-devel mailing list. Ideally your bug report should include complete detail of what the problem is, including instructions on how to reproduce the problem (for instance a test case binary and QEMU command line to run it, plus a description of what happens when it is run and what you expected it to do instead.)